# Finishing Rock Paper Scissors Game

Tags: actionscript-3

The code doesn't work although it won't display any errors. I'm trying to build a rock paper scissors game with 3 buttons and a score counter. I press the buttons but nothing changes on the screen.

Player 1 is the textbox for the user's score and Player 2 is the textbox for the computer's score.

```
var options: Array = [
"rock",
"paper",
"scissors"
];
var cp: String;
var res: String;
var score1: uint = 0;
var score2: uint = 0;
rockbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (ev) {
computerturn("rock");
});

paperbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (ev) {
computerturn("paper");
});

scissorsbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (ev) {
computerturn("scissors");
});
function computerturn(player: String) {
cp = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
computer.text = "Computer played " + cp;
if (cp == player) {
    res = "TIE";
    result.text = "TIE";
}
if ((cp == "rock") && (player == "paper")) {
    res = "Player wins: paper covers rock.";
    result.text = res;
    score1 += 1;
    Player1.text = score1.toString();
}
if ((cp == "rock") && (player == "scissors")) {
    res = "Computer wins: rock breaks scissors";
    result.text = res;
    score2 += 1;
    Player2.text = score2.toString();
}
if ((cp == "paper") && (player == "scissors")) {
    res = "Player wins: scissors cuts paper.";
    result.text = res;
    score1 += 1;
    Player1.text = score1.toString();
}
if ((cp == "paper") && (player == "rock")) {
    res = "Computer wins: paper covers rock.";
    result.text = res;
    score2 += 1;
    Player2.text = score2.toString();
}
if ((cp == "scissors") && (player == "rock")) {
    res = "Player wins: rock breaks scissors.";
    result.text = res;
    score1 += 1;
    Player1.text = score1.toString();
}
if ((cp == "scissors") && (player == "paper")) {
    res = "Computer wins: scissors cuts paper.";
    result.text = res;
    score2 += 1;
    Player2.text = score2.toString();
    }
}
result.text = res;
computer.text = "Computer played " + cp;
```

This is the code I based it on:

```
var options:Array= [
"rock",
"paper",
"scissors"
];
var cp:String;
var res:String;
function computerturn(player:String) {
//trace("player played "+player);

cp = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
//trace("computer played "+cp);
computer.text = "Computer played "+cp;
if (cp==player) {
    res = "TIE";
    result.text = "TIE";
}
if ((cp=="rock")&&(player=="paper")) {
    res="Player wins: paper covers rock.";
    result.text = res;
}
if ((cp=="rock")&&(player=="scissors")) {
    res="Computer wins: rock breaks scissors";
    result.text = res;
    gotoAndPlay("rockbreaks");
}
if ((cp=="paper")&&(player=="scissors")) {
    res="Player wins: scissors cuts paper.";
    result.text = res;
}
if ((cp=="paper")&&(player=="rock")) {
    res="Computer wins: paper covers rock.";
    result.text = res;
}
if ((cp=="scissors")&&(player=="rock")) {
    res="Player wins: rock breaks scissors.";
    result.text = res;
    gotoAndPlay("rockbreaks");
}
if ((cp=="scissors")&&(player=="paper")) {
    res="Computer wins: scissors cuts paper.";
    result.text = res;
}
}

rockbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (ev) {
computerturn("rock");}  );

paperbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (ev) {
computerturn("paper");}  );

scissorsbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function (ev) {
computerturn("scissors");}  );
stop();
```

Comment: `Player1` and `Player2` make me think of classes, instead of variables. Have you tried throwing a few `trace` statements in to check the logic is running as expected? Only other thing I can think of is to add `import flash.events.*`   at the start, for your clicks.

Comment: I based it from this code, can you try to compare these two and see what solution I can do? Thank you, your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Oh wait, where can I show the code?

Comment: As suggested by @stain88, please show minimal debugging effort and explain what you have tried so far to find out what the problem is. Use `trace()` or the debugger with breakpoints to see what values your variable have and compare them to what you expect them to be. You don't find errors by starring at different code snippets for hours wondering what might be wrong. It would be a fallacy to think that programming works like that. You have to work with the code, make assumptions about its behaviour and see if they are correct.

Comment: Ensure that everything is ok with your text inputs. Fonts, textFormat, size, position, color. The code looks correct.